# Beautiful Soup having trouble parsing output from mechanize

Tags: mechanize

```
def return_with_soup(url):
    #uses mechanize to tell the browser we aren't a bot
    #and to retrieve webpage
    #returns a soupified webpage
    browser = mechanize.Browser()    #I am made of human
    browser.set_handle_robots(False) #no bots here, no sir
    browser.open(url)
    #print browser.response().read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.response().read()) #this is where it breaks
    return soup
```

It throws this error in reference to the second to last line "Type error: module is not callable"

What's going on exactly?

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup was imported as a module.  So I had to change that line to:

```
BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(...)
```